# Issue with >= in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

I'm at my whit's end with this one, frustrated because I'm sure it's something simple and I need a second set of eyes. I've tried this several different ways and I continue to run into an issue where the query will run for a full 24 hours with no results...

I've narrowed the issue down to this section of the query:

```
WHERE sub.[Savings (%)] >= 10
```

I ran into so many issues that I ended up nesting the entire query into a sub query, trying to take most of my calculations out of the "Where" clause, but to no effect.

This is all part of a much larger query, so I'll post the abbreviated portion that is relevant.

Here's the very beginning of the query:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            LD.Region
            ,DM.ShortName AS DM
            ,D.Lcode
            ,LD.locationname
            ,D.UnitID
            ,D.dPlaced
            ,D.dCancelled
            ,D.sRentalType
            ,D.[Quoted Rate]
            ,Calcs.MinStdRate AS [Current Rate]
            ,-(Calcs.MinStdRate - D.[Quoted Rate]) AS [Savings ($)]
            ,((-(Calcs.MinStdRate - D.[Quoted Rate]))/NULLIF(D.[Quoted Rate],0))*100 AS [Savings (%)]
            ,D.sPlanName
            ,Calcs.[# Vacant]
        FROM...
```

Then this is the WHERE clause at the very end of the query that causes the issue. The entire query beneath "SELECT * FROM" (shown up above) is called "Sub":

```
    ) AS sub
        WHERE sub.[Savings (%)] >= 10
        AND sub.[Current Rate] <> 0 
        AND sub.[Quoted Rate] <> 0
```

When I notate "sub.[Savings (%)] >= 10 AND" out of the query, the whole thing runs in about 5 seconds. With it, it runs for hours on end and never produces results...

What am I missing?

Updating to show whole query per request:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        LD.Region
        ,DM.ShortName AS DM
        ,D.Lcode
        ,LD.locationname
        ,D.UnitID
        ,D.dPlaced
        ,D.dCancelled
        ,D.sRentalType
        ,D.[Quoted Rate]
        ,Calcs.MinStdRate AS [Current Rate]
        ,-(Calcs.MinStdRate - D.[Quoted Rate]) AS [Savings ($)]
        ,CAST(((-(Calcs.MinStdRate - D.[Quoted Rate]))/NULLIF(D.[Quoted Rate],0))*100 AS DECIMAL (18,2)) AS [Savings (%)]
        ,D.sPlanName
        ,Calcs.[# Vacant]
    FROM
        (SELECT
            s.sLocationCode AS lcode
            ,w.dPlaced
            ,L.dLease
            ,u.UnitID
            ,CASE
                WHEN w.dCancelled IS NOT NULL THEN w.dCancelled
                WHEN (w.dCancelled IS NULL AND w.dExpires <GETDATE()) THEN w.dExpires
                ELSE NULL
            END AS dCancelled
            ,CASE
                WHEN (w.dCancelled IS NOT NULL OR w.dExpires <GETDATE()) THEN 'Lost'
                WHEN w.QTRentalTypeID = 3 THEN 'Rented'
                WHEN (w.QTRentalTypeID = 2 OR w.QTRentalTypeID = 1) THEN 'Active'
            END AS sRentalType
            ,w.dcRate_Quoted AS 'Quoted Rate'
            ,c.sPlanName
            ,CONCAT(U.dcWidth,'x',U.dcLength) AS sSize
            ,UT.sTypeName
        FROM CompanyDBs.dbo.waitings AS W
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyDBs.dbo.Ledgers AS L
        ON W.LedgerID = L.LedgerID
        JOIN CompanyDBs.dbo.sites AS S
        ON W.SiteID = S.SiteID
        JOIN CompanyDBs.dbo.units AS U
        ON W.UnitID1 = U.UnitID
        JOIN CompanyDBs.dbo.UnitTypes AS UT
        ON U.UnitTypeID = UT.UnitTypeID
        JOIN CompanyDBs.dbo.ConcessionPlans AS C
        ON W.ConcessionID = C.ConcessionID
        WHERE W.dCancelled < GETDATE() AND W.dCancelled >= DATEADD(DD,-60,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            s.sLocationCode AS lcode
            ,w.dPlaced
            ,L.dLease
            ,u.UnitID
            ,CASE
                WHEN w.dCancelled IS NOT NULL THEN w.dCancelled
                WHEN (w.dCancelled IS NULL AND w.dExpires <GETDATE()) THEN w.dExpires
                ELSE NULL
            END AS dCancelled
            ,CASE
                WHEN (w.dCancelled IS NOT NULL OR w.dExpires <GETDATE()) THEN 'Lost'
                WHEN w.QTRentalTypeID = 3 THEN 'Rented'
                WHEN (w.QTRentalTypeID = 2 OR w.QTRentalTypeID = 1) THEN 'Active'
            END AS sRentalType
            ,w.dcRate_Quoted AS 'Quoted Rate'
            ,c.sPlanName
            ,CONCAT(U.dcWidth,'x',U.dcLength) AS sSize
            ,UT.sTypeName
        FROM CompanyDBs1.dbo.waitings AS W
        LEFT OUTER JOIN CompanyDBs1.dbo.Ledgers AS L
        ON W.LedgerID = L.LedgerID
        JOIN CompanyDBs1.dbo.sites AS S
        ON W.SiteID = S.SiteID
        JOIN CompanyDBs1.dbo.units AS U
        ON W.UnitID1 = U.UnitID
        JOIN CompanyDBs1.dbo.UnitTypes AS UT
        ON U.UnitTypeID = UT.UnitTypeID
        JOIN CompanyDBs1.dbo.ConcessionPlans AS C
        ON W.ConcessionID = C.ConcessionID
        WHERE W.dCancelled < GETDATE() AND W.dCancelled >= DATEADD(DD,-60,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) AS D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT
            P.SiteID
            ,P.sLocationCode
            ,P.UnitID
            ,p.UnitCODE
            ,groupeddata.[# Vacant]
            ,GroupedData.MinStdRate
        FROM
            (SELECT
                S2.sLocationCode
                ,S2.SiteID
                ,R2.UnitID
                ,CONCAT(S2.sLocationCode
                ,'-'
                ,S2.sSiteName
                ,' '
                ,R2.stypename
                ,' '
                ,CASE WHEN R2.iFloor > 1 THEN 'Up ' WHEN R2.ifloor < 1 THEN 'Down ' WHEN R2.ifloor = 1 THEN '1 ' END
                ,CASE WHEN R2.bPower = 1 THEN 'Power ' ELSE 'No Power ' END
                ,CASE WHEN R2.bClimate = 1 THEN 'CC ' ELSE 'No CC ' END
                ,CASE WHEN R2.bInside = 1 THEN 'In ' ELSE 'Out ' END
                ,CASE WHEN R2.bAlarm = 1 THEN 'Alarm ' ELSE 'No Alarm ' END
                ,CAST(R2.dcWidth AS FLOAT)
                ,'x'
                ,CAST(R2.dcLength AS FLOAT)) AS UnitCODE
                FROM Operations.dbo.RentRoll AS R2
                JOIN 
                (
                SELECT *
                FROM CompanyDBs.dbo.sites

                UNION ALL

                SELECT *
                FROM CompanyDBs1.dbo.sites
                ) AS S2
                ON R2.siteid = S2.SiteID
                WHERE 
                    R2.ddeleted is NULL
                    AND R2.bRentable = 1
                    AND R2.brented = 0 ) AS P
        JOIN
            (
            SELECT
                S.SiteID
                ,s.sLocationCode
                ,UnitCode.UnitCODE
                ,SUM(CASE
                        WHEN R.brented = 1 THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END) AS [# Vacant]
                ,MIN(R.dcStdRate) AS MinStdRate
            FROM Operations.dbo.RentRoll AS R
            JOIN 
                (
                SELECT *
                FROM CompanyDBs.dbo.sites

                UNION ALL

                SELECT *
                FROM CompanyDBs1.dbo.sites
                ) AS S
            ON R.siteid = S.SiteID
            JOIN
                (
                SELECT
                S1.SiteID
                ,UnitID
                ,CONCAT(S1.sLocationCode
                    ,'-'
                    ,S1.sSiteName
                    ,' '
                    ,R1.stypename
                    ,' '
                    ,CASE WHEN R1.iFloor > 1 THEN 'Up ' WHEN R1.ifloor < 1 THEN 'Down ' WHEN R1.ifloor = 1 THEN '1 ' END
                    ,CASE WHEN R1.bPower = 1 THEN 'Power ' ELSE 'No Power ' END
                    ,CASE WHEN R1.bClimate = 1 THEN 'CC ' ELSE 'No CC ' END
                    ,CASE WHEN R1.bInside = 1 THEN 'In ' ELSE 'Out ' END
                    ,CASE WHEN R1.bAlarm = 1 THEN 'Alarm ' ELSE 'No Alarm ' END
                    ,CAST(R1.dcWidth AS FLOAT)
                    ,'x'
                    ,CAST(R1.dcLength AS FLOAT)) AS UnitCODE
                FROM Operations.dbo.RentRoll AS R1
                JOIN 
                (
                SELECT *
                FROM CompanyDBs.dbo.sites

                UNION ALL

                SELECT *
                FROM CompanyDBs1.dbo.sites
                ) AS S1
                ON R1.siteid = S1.SiteID
                ) AS UnitCode
            ON CONCAT(R.siteid, R.unitid) = CONCAT(UnitCode.siteid,UnitCode.UnitID)
            WHERE 
                s.sLocationCode <> 'L003'
                AND s.sLocationCode <> 'L021'
                AND s.sLocationCode <> 'LSETUP'
                AND s.sLocationCode <> 'LTRAIN'
                AND R.bRented = 0
            GROUP BY s.siteid, s.slocationcode, UnitCode.UnitCODE
            ) AS GroupedData
        ON P.UnitCODE = GroupedData.UnitCODE
        ) AS Calcs
    ON CONCAT(D.lcode,D.unitid) = CONCAT(Calcs.slocationcode,Calcs.unitid)
    JOIN operations.dbo.westport_locationdata AS LD
    ON D.lcode = ld.lcode
    JOIN operations.dbo.Westport_DMs AS DM
    ON LD.DMID = DM.DMID
    ) AS sub
    WHERE sub.[Savings (%)] >= CAST(10.0 AS DECIMAL (18,2))
    AND sub.[Current Rate] <> 0 
    AND sub.[Quoted Rate] <> 0
```

Comment: What data type is `[Savings (%)]`? (I also suggest not using names that need to be quote identified).

Comment: Why do you put the WHERE clause in the outquery instead of the subquery ? Try to filter directly the main query like : (-(Calcs.MinStdRate - D.[Quoted Rate]))/NULLIF(D.[Quoted Rate],0) >= 0.1. Another way is to create a computed persistant column and filter it.

Comment: [Savings (%)] is a decimal(18,2) and normally I would not use brackets but this is for a final output for a report.

Comment: There are multiple sub queries that I am using to populate the main (the sub queries contain the calculations needed for the WHERE in the outer query). Maybe I am misunderstanding but I thought that by moving (-(Calcs.MinStdRate - D.[Quoted Rate]))/NULLIF(D.[Quoted Rate],0) >= 0.1 to the SELECT statement, I was creating a static column that could be filtered in the WHERE clause, as you suggest. Just weird that it isn;t working.

Comment: Can you get the execution query plan and paste it at https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ ?

Comment: @sccrbrg rewriting the query does not create a "static" column. You could achieve that only by populating a temporary table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are posting not the whole query. I could image that some indexes are missing.

I give you the strong advice to run your query in SQL Server Management Studio with the option "Query" -> "Include Actual Execution Plan" checked.

With this, SSMS will execute the query and tell you afterwards if indexes are missing and how much you could improve by setting them. You will get also a picture oh how the query is running.

Comment: I updated to include the whole query, although not entirely sure its relevant. This is probably not the most efficient way to have done this, but I already had bits and pieces of this lying around.

Comment: My initial thought was more along the lines of what you stated in terms of indexing, although since the query never fully runs, I don't think I will be able to see the execution plan? Most of these are curated tables from a third part software provider, I've never had an indexing issue before. Wouldn't that be unlikely given that the entire query runs without that one WHERE statement?

Comment: Thanks for updating. I can see a fairly complex query with UNION and the main issue is that `[Savings (%)]` is a calculated field. Therefore, the optimizer cannot quickly cut out unnecessary records. (In contrast to [Current Rate] where unnecessary records can be cut out very quickly). That means,  ALL rows have to be calculated, and only afterwards they can be filtered. This takes a tremendous amount of time.

Comment: PS: Did you try to run the query over night? Maybe you will then get the execution plan.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot run it overnight, we get a data carve from the software provider that is a complete replace via restore from backup. I'm not very well education on execution optimization. Would it be a viable alternative to inject the final results into a completely separate table, and the apply the WHERE to a SELECT * from that table?

Comment: @sccrbrg yes, inserting the results to a temporary table first, andthen filtering this table would be a good approach. There could also be other solutions, but your query is really very big so it would take some time to fully understand it.

Comment: That fixed it, pumped it into a table and queried from there. Thank you for the help. I need to spend more time researching execution plan strategies. This seems like a weird one, but maybe its not.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your where clause filter value `WHERE sub.[Savings (%)] >= cast(10.0 as decimal(18,2))` so there isn't an implicit conversion from `int` to `decimal`.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Implicit%20conversions%20are%20not%20visible,converts%20to%20date%20style%200](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=Implicit%20conversions%20are%20not%20visible,converts%20to%20date%20style%200).